# custom dialog box in Office Add-ins

Tags: office-addins, office-js

Is it possible to have custom dialog boxes in Office Add-ins. I have googled around but can't to find anything relevant.

If it's not possible, is there a work around someone can suggest.

It's a Word add-in with a task pane. I need to open a dialog box on click of a button within the pane, so that some selections can be done in the box and communicated back to the Document.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Update answer**

There is a [Dialog API](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui) that you can use to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no APIs in Word nor Office for creating dialog boxes. However, you could create your own dialog [using JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or you could open a new window using `window.open()` and have your own dialog in there.

Hope that helps,

Gabriel Royer

Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT